# Закрыть ключ API Яндекс Карт от внешнего доступа

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть сайт https://raionpoadresu.ru/ с бесплатным ключом API Яндекс Карт. Сегодня залочили ключ, т.к. новое ограничение 1000 запросов к геокодеру. На посещаемость 950 чел в день этого должно впритык хватить, но ключом  видимо пользуется не только этот сайт...

По внутренней запрограммированной статистике видим, что есть запросы по 5 в одну секунду из чего делаю вывод, что это делается программно.

Ключ можно заблокировать по IP или по адресу сайта, [см. документацию](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/limit.html). Первый не подходит, т.к. сайт бесплатный и открытый. Второй - подходит, но современные парсеры его обходят.

Вопрос, как закрыть ключ от внешнего доступа? Он сейчас в js-коде.

Comment: Зачем вы дергаете http геокодер с клиента? Проверить, не использует ли ваш ключ кто-то другой можно через техподдержку, но лучше всё-таки http запросы делать с сервера, а с клиента использовать геокодирование через js, где этой проблемы не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Если сделать на сервере, то спарсят страницу, это ещё проще:)
"а с клиента использовать геокодирование через js, где этой проблемы не будет" - вот тут не понял, можете уточнить? То есть делать часть запроса с клиента?

Comment: Геокодирование это просто операция, чтобы показать объект по адресу на карте; геокодировать можно через http-запрос с сервера или прямо из js кода методами JS API. Лимит в 1000 запросов только для http-запросов в серверный API.